# Why does VoiceOver read ranges / the word "to" in a weird way?

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover

When I use a range in my web page, for example "4 - 6" or "4 to 6", VoiceOver reads it out as something that sounds like "4 simmul 6" and I don't know why.

Originally, I assumed it was something to do with the dash. But I added an aria-label to put in the word "to" and it still reads it out incorrectly.

I've also tried doing it with something other than numbers, for example "point to point", and it reads it out correctly.

CodePen example here: https://codepen.io/xmeltrut/pen/PXRwvP

```
<p>8 to 4 MB/s</p>
<p>Point to point</p>
```

Turn on VoiceOver (F5) and scroll through the two paragraphs. The bottom one works, the top one is weird.

Comment: In what way is the top example on CodePen weird? For me, it reads "8 to 4 MB/s" as "eight to four megabytes slash s", which sounds all right?

Comment: Might be a certain combination of browser / OS? Quality isn't good, but here is what it is doing on all computers in our office: https://youtu.be/cHAoRSBZ6ek

Comment: Could you check whether it has something to do with the [dictionary or other settings](https://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/_1136.html) in VoiceOver?

Comment: VO on iOS seems to work ok.  I don't have a Mac to test it there.  What does the "closed caption" for VO say?  Does it show "4 to 8MB/s" but it says "simul" for "to"?  I can kind of hear that on youtube.  What if you change the voice?

Comment: Talkback (Android 8, latest Chrome) reads the codepen example as "four to eight megabytes per second". It even gets the units (and even slash as "per") right!

Comment: Aside: do you have the language correctly ide.tufied, say with `<html lang="en">`. (What WCAG calls the "language of page" and "language of parts".)

Comment: This may come down to the particular text-to-speech engine (or voice) being used. These are generally pluggable, separate to the screen reader. It could well be a bug at the TTS level.  Look at the "accessibility tree" in browser dev tools, to confirm the browser isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: I tried it with en-UK voice, it read eight to four correctly. Even the German voice gets it right. Issue is hard to reproduce.

Comment: Yes, I’m hearing “simul”. Lang attribute is set on our main codebase, but makes no difference. Changing the voice does work, though. By default, it’s set to Daniel Compact, but changing it to Daniel, Kate, or Kate Compact fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with the default voice on Mac, Daniel Compact. Changing to to Daniel, Kate or Kate Compact makes the issue go away.

You can change it by:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Select Accessibility
3. Select VoiceOver, and then "Open VoiceOver Utility"
4. Select Speech
5. Use the drop-down in the Voice column

Comment: yes, that's what i suggested in my comment from jan 4, 2019